# Unlock screen Ubuntu 20.04 takes long time

Tags: 20.04, gnome, lock-screen, unlock

I've installed new fresh Ubuntu 20.04. After locking the screen, for the first time in a while, unlocking is done too quickly but if immediately lock the screen again or lock it after a while, unlocking (checking password) takes a long time. I also checked [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1832812/comments/27). My ubuntu desktop-icons extensions are disabled and also I renamed that folder. But the problem exists. Also, I disabled extensions and nothing changed.